# Apply formula across pandas rows/ regression line

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to apply a formula across the rows of a data frame to get the trend of the numbers in the rows.

The below example works until the part where `.apply` is used.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
axisvalues=list(range(1,len(db.columns)+1))

def calc_slope(row):
    return scipy.stats.linregress(df.iloc[row,:], y=axisvalues)

calc_slope(1) # this works

df["New"]=df.apply(calc_slope,axis=1) # this fails *- "too many values to unpack"*
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: `scipy.stats.linregress()` returns more than one value.

Comment: That's what I messed up. I thought it was the way I was passing the arguments to the function. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need for one attribute:

```
def calc_slope(row):
    a = scipy.stats.linregress(row, y=axisvalues)
    return a.slope 

df["slope"]=df.apply(calc_slope,axis=1)
print (df)
          A         B         C         D     slope
0  0.444640  0.024624 -0.016216  0.228935 -2.553465
1  1.226611  1.962481  1.103834  0.645562 -1.455239
2 -0.259415  0.971097  0.124538 -0.704115 -0.718621
3  1.938422  1.787310 -0.619745 -2.560187 -0.575519
4 -0.986231 -1.942930  2.677379 -1.813071  0.075679
5  0.611214 -0.258453  0.053452  1.223544  0.841865
6  0.685435  0.962880 -1.517077 -0.101108 -0.652503
7  0.368278  1.314202  0.748189  2.116189  1.350132
8 -0.322053 -1.135443 -0.161071 -1.836761 -0.987341
9  0.798461  0.461736 -0.665127 -0.247887 -1.610447
```

And for all atributes convert named tuple to `dict` and then to `Series`. Output is new `DataFrame`, so if is necessary[`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
np.random.seed(1997)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
axisvalues=list(range(1,len(df.columns)+1))

def calc_slope(row):
    a = scipy.stats.linregress(row, y=axisvalues)
    return pd.Series(a._asdict())

print (df.apply(calc_slope,axis=1))
      slope  intercept    rvalue    pvalue    stderr
0 -2.553465   2.935355 -0.419126  0.580874  3.911302
1 -1.455239   4.296670 -0.615324  0.384676  1.318236
2 -0.718621   2.523733 -0.395862  0.604138  1.178774
3 -0.575519   2.578530 -0.956682  0.043318  0.123843
4  0.075679   2.539066  0.127254  0.872746  0.417101
5  0.841865   2.156991  0.425333  0.574667  1.266674
6 -0.652503   2.504915 -0.561947  0.438053  0.679154
7  1.350132   0.965285  0.794704  0.205296  0.729193
8 -0.987341   1.647104 -0.593680  0.406320  0.946311
9 -1.610447   2.639780 -0.828856  0.171144  0.768641
```

---

```
df = df.join(df.apply(calc_slope,axis=1))
print (df)
          A         B         C         D     slope  intercept    rvalue  \
0  0.444640  0.024624 -0.016216  0.228935 -2.553465   2.935355 -0.419126   
1  1.226611  1.962481  1.103834  0.645562 -1.455239   4.296670 -0.615324   
2 -0.259415  0.971097  0.124538 -0.704115 -0.718621   2.523733 -0.395862   
3  1.938422  1.787310 -0.619745 -2.560187 -0.575519   2.578530 -0.956682   
4 -0.986231 -1.942930  2.677379 -1.813071  0.075679   2.539066  0.127254   
5  0.611214 -0.258453  0.053452  1.223544  0.841865   2.156991  0.425333   
6  0.685435  0.962880 -1.517077 -0.101108 -0.652503   2.504915 -0.561947   
7  0.368278  1.314202  0.748189  2.116189  1.350132   0.965285  0.794704   
8 -0.322053 -1.135443 -0.161071 -1.836761 -0.987341   1.647104 -0.593680   
9  0.798461  0.461736 -0.665127 -0.247887 -1.610447   2.639780 -0.828856   

     pvalue    stderr  
0  0.580874  3.911302  
1  0.384676  1.318236  
2  0.604138  1.178774  
3  0.043318  0.123843  
4  0.872746  0.417101  
5  0.574667  1.266674  
6  0.438053  0.679154  
7  0.205296  0.729193  
8  0.406320  0.946311  
9  0.171144  0.768641
```

Comment: Can you please show how the same thing could be done if the data frame had missing values? The linregress function doesn't return unless all the data is there. Could we somehow mask the missing values and return the linregress info for the values that are in the rows?

Comment: Unfortunately now I an on phone only, so can you create new question? I will online tomorow.

Comment: Thank you! Posting question now

Comment: OK, super. I am waiting for it.